# Magnific popup - YouTube - An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: 0AztKrvPxxy7y8ia)

Tags: html, youtube, playback, magnific-popup

I'm using magnific popup to embed my YouTube videos on my website. It works like a charm with some videos, but with other videos I get "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: 0AztKrvPxxy7y8ia)".

Any ideas about what could cause this? Has it something to do with video settings on YouTube? The videos are in identical format. I've tried to flush cache, history, and so on. Same thing happens in different browsers. I have no ad-blocking extensions. I really don't know why it happens to some of the videos, and not others.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I still don't know, what's been causing it, as both divs are identical. But I've copied the working  with the video, changed the link, and it starting working.